# PayPal Sandbox not working on online website

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to implement the PayPal API for credit card payments.
On my local machine (localhost) it's working, but when I am trying the same code with the same details online, it doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}
Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token.
```

Here is the configuration code:

```
$apiContext->setConfig(
    [
        'mode' => 'sandbox',
        'log.LogEnabled' => false,
        'log.FileName' => '../PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE', // PLEASE USE `FINE` LEVEL FOR LOGGING IN LIVE ENVIRONMENTS
        'cache.enabled' => true,
    ]
);
```

Any ideas, guys? I would be forever grateful!

Also, is there something else I need to take into consideration when using their API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some code of your config? I believe you have to set some mode to live that default goes to Sandbox.

Comment: I have updated my question with the configuration code.